# Android Map Fragment going behind toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments

Having an issue with a map fragment on my one activity, basically i have created a bottom navigation view and my map fragment is going behind my bottom navigation view no matter what i do. I'm not sure how to get it to respect my layout and sit above my bottom navigation view.

I have a scrollview with all my content inside it, including the map fragment and then a bottom navigation view outside of my scroll view so that it remains fixed to the bottom of the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <!-- My content -->

             <fragment
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/details"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    map:cameraZoom = "15"
                    map:uiZoomControls = "true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_toolbar"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/toolbar_item" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update code

**android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar_footer"**

```
...
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar_footer"
    android:fillViewport="true">
...
```

Comment: That didn't help, added an image to show what it is doing.

Comment: Not sure how i missed that, thank you! That fixed it.